Were US men and women ever so divided in national polls?
Reportedly

The numbers are stunning. An NBC poll this week found men favour Trump over Harris by 12 points, 52% to 40%. Among women, Harris leads Trump by 21 points: 58% to 37%. Put the two together and you have a gender chasm of 33 points. Men may not be from Mars and women may not be from Venus, but when it comes to choosing a US president, they are on different planets.

Is the number cherry picked? Is it historically unprecedented in US politics?

I'm a skeptical that the source is accurate, because this implies a much bigger Harris lead in the polls than any national polls that I've seen.

@ohwilleke The quoted poll has Harris at +5. With the current 538 average at Harris +2.5, the poll is on the high side, but well within the normal variability you see in polls simply due to finite sampling. No reason to be more sceptical about the gender gap result simply because of this. But of course it would be better to average the gender gap in many polls to get a more robust result.

Until I opened the question and read the body, I had been reading its title as if it were using the archaic sense of "ever" meaning "always." Perhaps it would be clearer to change the tense: "Have US men and women ever been so divided..." or even "Have [they] ever before been so divided...." Similarly, I saw "divided" as referring to pollsters' use of gender as a category, not to the difference of opinion reflected by the poll results. I can't think of a clearly better way of expressing that at the moment, but perhaps someone with more experience discussing polls will be able to.

Yes, this is the largest divide between men and women in polling data for a presidential election that I can find1 demographic polling results for, and the previous maximum was 2020.
The columnist in that article has made a mistake in reporting the sum of the two gender gaps, one for Trump and one for Harris, as one "gender gap". The academic definition is the gap for the leading or winning candidate.

[% Women for Leading or Winning Candidate] – [% Men for Leading or Winning Candidate] = Gender Gap

For the current polling, that would be the 18 point difference for Harris, rather than the combined 18 + 15 for Harris + Trump.
Both the academic definition, and this author's method, agree that 2024 is the widest divide between the voting patterns of men and women.

I can only find polling data split by gender going back to 1976 before there starts to be gaps, so there may have been a point between 1920 and 1976 where there was an equal, or larger gap, but I don't know of it.


Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Put the two together and you have a gender chasm of 33 points.

First of all figure of 33 points makes no sense at all. But just seems to be an iteration of "big scary numbers get clicks".
Like there's probably already a confusion about "percent point differences" not being a "difference in percent"..., but that's certainly a new low with regards to statistical aptitude. Also you wouldn't really count the percent point difference between candidates either as that is a 0 sum game so any gain of 1 percent point of candidate A would come with a 1 percent point loss of candidate B so an increase of 2 percent points.
What you would apparently do instead is look at the same candidate and their approval rates among male or female voters and that difference. From that wiki link on the voting gender gap:

(e.g., if 55 percent of men support a candidate and 44 percent of women support the same candidate, there is an 11-point gender gap).


(e.g., men +10 Republican and women +12 Democratic is not equivalent to a 22-point gender gap)

So in other words the gap would be: 18 points for Harris or 15 points for Trump. That being said if you scroll down to the section marking the gender gap in the exit polls since the 80s (you can also check the demographic distribution of earlier elections but though they are present they are usually lower), then that is indeed quite a high margin. Usually it would average at 8 percent points, it peaked in 1996-2000 then dropped to 7 and since then steadily rose till 12 in 2020. But if it would be 15 or 18 that would indeed be a new high even without unnecessarily inflating the numbers.

There's still some confusion from that Wikipedia article, it defines "Gender gaps" (plural) and then goes on to list "The gender gap" (singular) for each year 1980-2020. I think that's the gender gap of the winning candidate, so we can't know which of 15 or 18 is "the" gap for 2024 (although if these polls are accurate, Harris wins with a gap of 18)

This is somewhat unnecessarily aggressively formulated, but it's a fair point that the calculation method in the article from my Q was not by typical academic/polling standards.

In what sense is it bullshit to describe a methodology for computing a statistic, then apply that methodology and say what the result is? Your objections are that the statistic they computed is unusual, and that it doesn't have a straightforward real-world interpretation. Both valid criticisms, but neither of them amounts to statistical malpractice. It would be bullshit (or at least, wrong) if he called the "33 points" figure a "gender gap", but he didn't.

@Caleth Yes it seems to be the gender gap for the winner and talking about multiple of those makes it plural ;) Also it's a 2 party system so the respective other gap is very likely to be a mirror image so mentioning one is often sufficient. So in that case women actually support Harris while for men the missing 3% went to an option other than Trump or Harris. Also the "other option" could be "undecided" or "no comment" or whatnot, which is likely to be smaller for exit polls making it even more likely to receive a mirror image in terms of the gap.

@IVFcomesfromthetip Yeah, maybe I should revise that later.

@kaya3 "the phrase “gender gap” doesn’t do it justice. In ways that go deeper [...]." So in my books he very much implies that his "gender chasm" is a gender gap ... on steroids. But actually it's neither what is usually referred to as gender gap, nor is it a particularly useful figure. Also with all the talk about chasms we're still talking about >10% deviations from 50%. With all that he has mentioned you would expect that chasm to be much bigger, but that's a different point... But fair enough, he does mention that methodology, though how many people read beyond headlines and buzzwords?

@haxor789 "nor is it a particularly useful figure" - it can be understood as the difference in the predicted popular vote between if only men voted (R+12) vs. if only women voted (D+21). Obviously neither of those hypotheticals will ever happen, but it's not a wrong way of thinking about the difference between men's vs. women's voting intentions. I agree that by framing the issue that way tends to overstate the difference because it counts the differences for both candidates, tending to make it twice as large as the numbers usually reported. I just disagree that it means the author has ...

... done something statistically wrong. Consider measures of spread - the interquartile range (IQR) and the standard deviation (SD). IQR measures the difference between a typical low value and a typical high value, whereas SD measures the distance of a typical value from the centre. So IQR likewise will tend to be "twice as much" for the same reason a diameter is twice a radius. What this means is that you can't look at an IQR and compare it to an SD, because that's apples to oranges. It doesn't mean reporting an IQR is inept. Anyway, I removed my downvote after your edit.

@kaya3 Not just twice as large could be as much as four times as large. The thing is in a two party system one candidate's gain is another candidates loss, so if men and women support different candidates with a narrow margin of x, then then other candidate will have -x the difference is 2x and if you add the other gender it's 4x. So if you look at how much their preferred candidate beats the majority, it's T+2 and H+8 so it's rather the fact that their less preferred candidates score T-13 and H-10 which makes that difference. So we assume the unaccounted percentage points go towards...

... the currently leading candidates, that's 37:63 vs 60:40. So a 23/20 point gender gap, while if they go to the losing candidate it's 52:48 and 58:42 so a 4/16 gender gap. While the chasm would be 43 or 20. So in one case the chasm is ~20 points higher while in the other case it's almost the same as the gap. Not to mention that in absolute numbers even 60:40 isn't that big of a deal, if it weren't at least 40% for a liar, fraudster, demagogue who think he can win elections by declaring as much. Any the crazy thing is the last sentence isn't even slander, but largely court approved.

@kaya3 Also that's not exactly what the IQR is. Essentially where the median takes the middle most value so literally in 0.1, 1, 3, 1000, 10000 you'd take the 3 because in the ordered list it's the middle. With the IQR you'd take the difference of the value at roughly 1/4 and 3/4. So you don't double, the difference is always between the two. While the standard deviation computes the mean and sums the squared deviations from the mean and takes the square root of that sum. So essentially a mean of deviations from the mean, which seems to be more accurate but harder to explain to a layman...

@haxor789 "could be as much as four times as large" No, you are comparing to some other statistic which would be half as large as the "gender gap" as it's normally defined. The "gender chasm" in this opinion piece is the sum of two gender gaps, so straightforwardly it will tend to be twice as large as one gender gap. "Also that's not exactly what the IQR is [...] you don't double" I didn't say the IQR is "double" anything, or that you double anything to compute it; you seem not to have actually read my description of the IQR.

@kaya3 It's never directly computing a gender gap. It computes a lead of a candidate by the difference of candidates and for that you'd just need their score above 50% in a two party system. They do accidentally compute 2x the gender gap as c1w-c2w + c2m- c1m = c1m-c1w + c2m-c2w which coincidentally are the respective gender gaps but there's no indication that this would be deliberate and the separate "chasm" (12+21) are NOT the respective gender gaps (15+18). Also you said that: "So IQR likewise will tend to be "twice as much" for the same reason"

@haxor789 Yes, you have algebraically shown that what he computed is the sum of two gender gaps, which explains why it tends to be "twice as much" as a gender gap, as I said. On the IQR, you have cut short the quote of what I said: "... for the same reason a diameter is twice a radius". That is, the IQR is the difference between points on two opposite sides, as opposed to a point on the side and a point in the centre (as the SD is analogous to). That doesn't mean it is "double" anything or that you multiply some other number by 2 to compute it.

Your assertion that 12+21 and 15+18 aren't computing the same thing has me baffled, since you just showed yourself that they are the same. They are different ways of arriving at the same result, and that result is a sum of two gender gaps.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Leaving aside the issues of whether the actual figure reported should be 33%, 16.5%, 18%, or something else, it does seem entirely possible that the figures were "cherry-picked" in the sense that a single poll with an unusually large gender gap was used.
This poll shows a gender gap for Harris support of about 18% (up to rounding errors).  This seems unusually large. 538 discussed the gender gap for Harris in August, finding about an 11% gap, and again very recently, finding about a 9% gap, both using figures produced from a large number of polls.
Those figures are both lower than the actual gender gap in 2016 of 13% for Clinton (or even the gap for Biden in 2020). I would be very surprised if there wasn't a single poll from 2016 giving a gender gap even bigger than this single poll from 2024.

So maybe the gender gap now is similar to 2016/2020. Anyway, the real gap would be the one on election day, i.e. what can be gathered from exit polls.

It's not possible to "Put the two together" and "have a gender chasm of 33 points."
The so-called chasm -- which is not a large gender gap as presented -- but called women's vote is 21 at this point. One must take the difference of 58% to 37% to form the womens vote. It's possible to claim a 52% to 40% or 12 pts for similar mens vote. Those numbers cannot be summed to create a 'chasm' nevermind a gender gap.
At this point, 8% of the men's vote while 5% of women's vote are missing from the Trump/Harris tally. I suggest that the missing votes went to a) independents, b) undecided or c) not voting because it is a POLL and not the actual VOTE.
The gender gap at this point is either 15 pts with a large 11% missing (Trump 52% to 37%); or 18 pts (Harris 58% to 40%) with a smaller 2% missing.
The 18 pts appear more accurate at this point. I'm going with 17 pts for the final. So it appears that the gender gap is widening but almost half of the 33 that is suggested by the professionals at The Guardian -- using data from NBC.
The misleading use of an aggregated sum is hopefully provided in the following:
In 2020, 52% of men prefer oranges; while 58% of women prefer apples. That leaves 48% of men preferring apple; and 42% of women preferring oranges. Most will agree that the gender gap is 10 pts. The gender gap for apples is 10 pts; and the gender gap for oranges is 10 pts. One cannot claim there is a gender gap of 20 pts.
The problem is throwing in a a few people who prefer bananas. But that banana problem does not permit such calculation.
Next year, 51% of men prefer oranges; while 58% of women prefer apples. 47% of men prefer apples; 2% prefer bananas. This leaves 41% of women preferring oranges and 1% preferring bananas. The gender gap for apples is 11 pts; and the gender gap for oranges is 10 pts;  It is not 21 pts. The gender gap for bananas is 1 pt.
The recorded gender gap is for the winning party. 10 pts and then 11 pts. People moving toward bananas provide the growth in that gap.
One could compare the sums as long a) the history was provided and b) one is reminded that the values are almost double of the meaningful number simply due to the low preference for the other options.

Yeah, but has it ever been wider for some topic or another or a presidential election? 2016 maybe?

16, 17 or 18 pts is significantly wider than than the previous 12 pts. But it isn't anything close to 33 pts, a number used as hard scientific data to provide the essay's grand intro to Trump the misogynist.

You can still compare the 33 number with previous results by using the same method, i.e. adding the magnitudes for the top 2 candidates. 33 is way higher than 23, just as 18 is way higher than 12.

"It's not possible" to add two numbers and say what the result is? Or if you add the numbers the result is not a "chasm"? I am finding it very hard to make any sense of this answer. Also where does your figure of 17 points come from?

You can compare those numbers: 12 was the last 2020 number for the gender gap. So double it to get 24. So 24 to 33. Yup "it has widened". But the comparison between 12 and 33 is inaccurate, misleading and ultimately misinformation.

@ABoston The article never compares 12 and 33. It doesn't list any previous values.

the article doesn't list the number but does clearly refer to the bonafide "gender gap". in fact, the comparison to previous historical values is the entire basis for the articles argument. but as several pointed out, including yourself its calculated incorrectly.

The author's point stands when you compare 24 and 33, which is what the 2020 numbers are by this method. It could also have compared 12 and 18, which is what the numbers are by the academic metric. You are comparing 12 and 33 and saying that the article is invalid on that basis. You can make a mistake of terminology and still be right

The article neither lists 24 nor any historical figures. And nope the article is not invalid but elevated through the use of incorrect calculations and misleading comparison. As pointed out the correct calculation (see Caleth's accepted answer) is %women for winning - % men for winning. Thus the winning side will be positive; the other negative. Or, vice versa. A comparison of the 'womens vote' to 'mens vote' figures in absolute terms is also misleading.

Yes.
For the above 2024 NBC poll, make an adjustment of the sampling error of 3 percentage points to each of the two groups (male and female) and the "gender chasm" measure could be as low as 27 points.
Now take the actual 2020 elections (based on National Election Pool exit polls):

Male: 53% Trump, 45% Biden
Female: 42% Trump, 57% Biden

So, the "gender chasm" measure for the 2020 elections was 23 points. Make an adjustment of the sampling error of 3 percentage points to each of the above two groups. Then this measure could've been as large as 29 points and so possibly greater than the same measure for the above 2024 NBC poll.

I think you have a good argument in saying that the chasm was already present in the last election, and it was nearly as wide as current polls reflect, but you should cook a little bit more the answer to gain an upvote. While a 3% of margin of error could account for the differences in gap measurements between the 2020 and 2024 elections, for the 2020 election gap to be wider than the current one (so your answer of 'Yes' could be right) it needs the 2020 poll to have underestimated the gap to the max of that 3%, and the 2024 to have overestimated equally. That's unlikely.

@Rekesoft: A simple statistical test would show that the "gender chasm" in the 2024 NBC poll is not greater than that in the 2020 election exit polls.

Based on what you posted the difference in support for men went from 8 points in Trumps favor in 2020 to 12 points in his favor in 2024. For women it went from 15 points against Trump in 2020 to 21 points against him in 2024. Seems clear to me that the difference has only grown.

You are aware that the probability of both samples being at the edge of the confidence interval is both probabilities squared? I.e., both are well within the 95% interval so that, say, each deviation has a probability of 10% -- then the probability that both coincide is only 1%, i.e., far outside regular confidence measures.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica But both samples being at the edge is only one possible scenario. There's about a 10% chance that at least one was entirely outside the confidence interval entirely, for example. I'm also not sure if assuming an error margin of 3 percentage points on the gender-separated poll is valid in the first place. The error margin has to be higher than the aggregate poll, because each is based on half the sample size.

@DM True; I just wanted to point out that one cannot simply say "each one is within the error margins, so it's not significant".

There was a democrat expectation in 2016, that women will vote with a higher probability for Hillary. Essentially, they tried to create or utilize a gender-based division of the society. A similar one like the race-based divison.
This failed. Women voted Hillary actually in a smaller ratio as men.
Next time, they nominated Biden, but the VP was a woman and they won. However, the idea remained. Now we see a re-try.
Opinion polls are also a way to actually alter the voting results, simply because part of the not determined voters like to vote for the winner. Thus, polls can be considered also as media devices, to help the non-determined voters in their decision.
Real party and campaign leaders have also real opinion polls, these are much more detailed, and their results are not public.
It is some like a "political voodo".
Such statements like this nbc poll, can be considered real only if also the pro-Trump opinion polls say the same (as far I know, there is none).

Is this a "yes, they were so divided before" or the opposite? It’s hard for me to tell and may benefit from spelling it out.

"Women voted Hillary actually in a smaller ratio as men." is not actually true https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/2018/08/09/an-examination-of-the-2016-electorate-based-on-validated-voters/

@IVFcomesfromthetip As far I know, there were many disappointed voices (particularly that she actually won the popular vote). Example. Little googling shows these voices. Afaik the women voted against her, other not, resulting that voters have seen primary a democrat in her and not a woman.

@MisterMiyagi How about this?

That is right, afaik only the white women voted against her. I think that is a rejection of the woke ideology - note that even the white women might feel her job being threated by black women. That they can not enter many jobs because white males are priorized before them, that is what they are already accustomed to. But racing with black women, boosted by positive discrimination, that is a new development, and they rejected this new development. I think, that would be their game theoretical rationality. Beside that, they can become the wife of a white man but not of a black woman.

I don't know why your answer received so many down votes! It is essentially the same as the answer by Especially Lime but yours was first. Perhaps the lack of sourcing? idk. Also, as you said, the division isn't solely by sex; it is also by race. Finally, you bring up a very important point, about the effect of polls on voter behavior! In the US this is not considered so much, but in the UK there is recognition of it. In some countries, polling is restricted for that reason.

@EllieK I am very happy to see your comment. The downs happened because the polls measured a much bigger democrat advantage in the last 2 elections. Indirectly I stated that the democratic party tried to manipulate the voters on this way, although it is not in the text. In my home country, opinion polls count as part of campaign, by law (thus, for example, they are forbidden to publish where/when it is forbidden to campaign). Unfortunately, our wonderful democrats do not want to understand this. No issue that I am not even an USA guy.

This simply does not answer the question. It’s a commentary on the election for which Clinton (what’s with the selective first name bias, by the way?) and Biden were running, plus some seemingly tangential commentary on polls as a political device. Nowhere does this answer address whether men and women were ever so divided in national polls.
